# Why does the for loop in this shell script perform the first iteration twice before doing the second one?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bash script:

```
#! usr/bin/env bash
# test bash script to call python scripts

cd ~/python
for ((i = 1; i <= 2; i++)); do
 python3 test_0$i.py; done
cd ~/bash
```

that pulls test_0x.py files from the python directory and runs them in order.
test_01.py is a single print statement, whereas test_02 is a for loop.

I was expecting it to:

1. navigate to ~/python
2. run test_01.py
3. run test_02.py
4. navigate back to ~/bash

the bash script runs test_01.py, then test_01.py *again*, and only then test_02.py.
is this some quirk of shell-scripts i am simply too green to anticipate, or is there something wrong with my — albeit very basic — code?

I am using an ubuntu terminal through windows subsystem for linux, if that affects things.

Comment: Does `test02.py` import `test01.py`? There's nothing wrong with your shell code; to confirm the loop only executes `python3` twice, try adding something like `echo "Running test0$i.py"` as the first line of the loop

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". Your script contains multiple errors that shellcheck could tell you about and, given the shebang you're using, I highly doubt if what you've shown us is a real script you're running. Post a real [mcve] after it's shellchecvk-clean if you'd like help.

Comment: You did not show how you run the script, but unless you source it, the last `cd` won't have any effect. From a bash viewpoint, I don't see an error with the loop, and I would run it with `set -x` for getting debug output.

Comment: what's the output when you run `run test_01.py` manually from the command prompt? what's the output when you run `run test_02.py` manually from the command prompt?

Comment: @EdMorton The website you sent me only asked me to correct my shebang, so I'm not sure where you got multiple errors from. this is also not a 'real' script whatever you mean by that, but rather a script i wrote while trying to learn shell scripting. i'm sorry i insulted your sensibilities by posting a question on a forum.

Comment: @markp-fuso test_01.py should give me a single print statement, something asinine i put there just to test the shell script. test_02 is a print statement inside a 'for x in range' loop.

but when run through bash, i get the test_01 print statement executed, then the test_01 statement again, then test_02.

Comment: @GirishManjunath then you went to the wrong web site or didn't copy/paste the script from your question into it or didn't bother to correct your shebang and then see what other issues shellcheck would then find as you have 2 `cd`s there without `|| exit` that shellcheck would have told you about and it'd probably also tell you about the unquoted variable. You didn't insult my sensibilities by posting a question on a forum but you did waste everyone's time by posting a question that didn't contain a script you wanted help to debug and not doing what the [tag:bash] tag you used tells you to do.

Comment: If you continue giving snotty responses to helpful suggestions then YMMV being able to get help on this forum or anywhere else. I see in [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23290753/girish-manjunath) you describe yourself as "Always looking for; and rarely providing; help" - try helping some people and you may get a better understanding and appreciation for the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running through WSL should have no impact in this case.

There are a few problems with your script, but the ones that are visible, at least, wouldn't cause an additional loop.

To debug the *loop* part of the problem, I'd start by:

1. From the command-line, run the same loop in the same directory, but with an `echo` in place of the Python invocation itself:

   ```
   cd ~/python
   for ((i = 1; i <= 2; i++)); do
     echo test_0$i.py; done
   ```
2. If that works, make the same adjustment to the script and test it.
3. If that works, as mentioned in the comments, check `test_01.py` to see if it is calling `test_02.py`.  Try running it manually at the command-line and/or visually inspect it.

As @user1934428 mentioned in the comments, running with `set -x` may also yield useful information.

---

##### Other issues

- There is a typo in your shebang line (at least as you entered it here in your question) - `#! usr/bin/env bash`.  The purpose of a shebang line is to tell system what program should *execute* your script (e.g., when called as `./script.sh`).  This is simply not going to work.

  The proper shebang line would be:

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  ```
- However, if you really are expecting it to run as a script, then we come to the second issue.  You mention that step 4 should be to *"navigate back to ~/bash"*.

  This will not have the *intended effect* when executing a script via the shebang line.  It may *appear* to work, but what really happens is that the shell will still be in whatever directory it *started in*.  This *may* be the `~/bash` directory, but it may not be.  For example:

  ```bash
  cd ~
  ~/bash/script.sh
  ```

  This would leave you back in the `~` directory after the script completes.

  Why? When using a shebang line, the script is *executed* by a separate shell invocation.  It's inside *this* shell (running as a subprocess) that the `cd` takes place.  As a `cd` is an environment change (the `PWD` environment variable), it can't be propagated back to the calling process.

  If you really need the script to be able to change the directory for the calling shell (and you probably don't), then you would need to `source` the script instead of *executing* it.  `source script.sh` will process the script *inside* the currently running Bash shell, allowing it to change the current directory of the current shell.

Comment: i corrected the shebang line, and removed the final cd statment. while the echo statement still only gives one output, invoking python3 still makes test_01 execute twice. i'm very new to shell scripting, by 'running with set -x' do you mean i call `bash [script.sh] set -x` in the terminal, or do you mean i have to add a line in the script called `set -x`?

Comment: test_02.py is definitely not calling test_01.py, i've already checked that.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the shebang line, removed the final `cd` command, and then restarted the wsl instance. The bash script now works as i expected it to. I don't know what fixed it, but I suspect that, in my ignorance, I was doing something stupid in the background that caused this error. Thank you to all who answered.

Comment: This sort of information rates as a comment. Glad you solved your problem (I didn't downvote it)